# Is there any way to change the way View works for different classes?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have created an S3 class in R that is based on a list. However, I want it to display in View as as if it were a data frame. Basically, I want View to use the as.data.frame method to view it instead of showing it in the way it shows lists. Is there any way to do this?

Here's a trivial example:

```
as.myclass <- function(x) {
  x <- list(x = x, y = 1, z = 2)
  class(x) <- "myclass"
  return(x)
}

as.data.frame.myclass <- function(x) {
  return(x$x)
}

View(as.myclass(mtcars))                      # This is what it does
View(as.data.frame(as.myclass(mtcars)))       # This is what I would like the previous command to do
```

Comment: The documentation seems to claim this should happen by default as long as the requisite `as.data.frame` method exists but the source code is somewhat hidden. Have you tried using S4?

Comment: Any reason why you don't keep the "data.frame" class along with "myclass" ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper this is just an example for simplicity. The actual thing I'm working on holds a data frame and a few other items and the as.data.frame method makes some other adjustments to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define a method `as.data.frame.myclass` `View()` will work... unless you use Rstudio, which has its own version that takes precedence, and behaves differently.

If you use `utils::View()` you'll have the R gui output:

```
as.myclass <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- "myclass"
  return(x)
}

as.data.frame.myclass <- as.data.frame.list
utils::View(as.myclass(mtcars))
```

Now if you use Rstudio it'll be a bit more complex, we need to override it and make it generic :

```
View <- function(x, title) UseMethod("View")
View.default <- function(x, title) eval(substitute(
  get("View", envir = as.environment("package:utils"))(x,title)))
View.myclass <- function(x, title) eval(substitute(
  get("View", envir = as.environment("package:utils"))(as.data.frame(x),title)))
View(as.myclass(mtcars))
```

It would be easier however if you can afford to keep the `data.frame` class along with myclass :

```
as.myclass <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("data.frame","myclass")
  return(x)
}
View(as.myclass(mtcars)) # without overriding `View()`!
```

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think it will work to keep data.frame as a class. Is it ok to mask View, though? I mean, that seems kind of extreme. I know it's fine for my own purposes, but would CRAN accept a package that did that?

Comment: Yes they would, but the conflict would be signalled by a message by default when the package is attached, and it's better to avoid overriding base functions without a good reason generally speaking. What about defining `View2()`,  `V()` or `view_myclass()` ?

Comment: FYI the package tibble has a function `view()`, very similar to `View()`. I proposed them to make it generic a few days ago as a matter of fact but chances that they accept are low I guess, you can support the request here : https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/695

Comment: it works fine if you just use View(as.data.frame(myobject)). It's just annoying. I guess I'll probably have to go with that, though. Thanks for your help.